# The menu is jumpy on hover

Tags: html, css

The menu is jumpy on hover... What should I do to make the other elements stay in one place when I hover something?

On hover it is set to bold, which moves everything to the sides...

```css
.navlinks ul {
   margin-top: 45px;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .navlinks ul li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .navlinks ul li a {
   color: black;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
 }
 .navlinks ul li a:hover {
   font-weight: 700;
   border-bottom: none;
 }
 .navlinks ul > li:not(:first-child) {
   margin-left: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="navlinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to remove the bold? Remove `font-weight: 700;` from the CSS.

Comment: Its because the font weight changes drastically from 300 to 700. You can try decreasing the final font weight to a lesser value or increase it gradually.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that setting the width on `<li>` to a static one, or using display:table to design the menu.

Both examples here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8rw1tq6/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `text-shadow` to mimic the bold font. This won't affect the layout.

```css
.navlinks ul {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 0;
}
.navlinks ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navlinks ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
}
.navlinks ul li a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 1px 1px black;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.navlinks ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navlinks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a clever solution actually.